# Transforming async lambda only throwing an OperationCanceledException to synchronous variant

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I have this small test in `.NET 6`, which works fine (it's green).

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory = async token => throw new OperationCanceledException();
Assert.True(taskFactory(CancellationToken.None).IsCanceled);
```

However, the compiler (rightfully?) complains: `warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously`. I could not figure out a way to transform this into a synchronous variant.
I tried these 2 options for the lambda

1. without async: `token => throw new OperationCanceledException()`. It's pretty clear to me that this will just throw the exception directly on the stack instead of wrapping it in the task, but this is what the IDE suggested.
2. `token => Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException())`. This goes to `IsFaulted` instead of `IsCanceled`.

What is the correct way to transfrom this to a synchronous variant?

Edit: The point of this snippet was to test whether some CUT deals correctly with the OperationCanceledException being `emitted` from a taskFactory. So the exception still needs to emitted, possibly thrown, in the solution. **I am not simply looking for a way to set a task to canceled.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could await a completed task:

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory = async token =>
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
};
        
Assert.True(taskFactory(CancellationToken.None).IsCanceled);
```

However your test does have a race condition, although it's likely to usually succeed. But if you change it to this:

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory = async token =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
};

var task = taskFactory(CancellationToken.None);
Console.WriteLine(task.IsCanceled);
```

it will print `false`. To fix that, you have to wait for the task to complete:

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory = async token =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
};

var task = taskFactory(CancellationToken.None);
Task.WaitAny(task);
Console.WriteLine(task.IsCanceled);
```

Note that I'm using `Task.WaitAny()` to wait for the task to complete *without* throwing a `TaskCanceledException`. If you simply `await task;` it will of course throw that exception.

Comment: So you're saying that the first example you give has the race condition? The C# docs say: "When the await operator is applied to the operand that represents an already completed operation, it returns the result of the operation immediately without suspension of the enclosing method." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await#await-operator-in-the-main-method - So it should be fine, no?

Comment: @ltjax Sorry, I wasn't very clear: I actually meant: You have to be careful because if you change the code, you could introduce a race condition because you're not awaiting the task. The code as you have it should work, but only because of the specific implementation you have.

Comment: That's an okay situation here though, because it is in a test. If you break the code with a race condition, the test will show it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the low-level APIs as well to achieve the desired outcome in a synchronous way.

```
TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory = token => tcs.Task;
```

With this approach your delegate remains sync (don't need to use the `async` keyword)

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new(0);
cts.Token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
```

Here we connect the Task and Cancellation primitives via a simple callback.
We cancel the Task right away.

And that's it :) A working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pv3IkZ).